# How to implement this as a function to get rid off trailing garbage?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have string which should be a `json` but at the end and only at the end it has trailing garbage characters of arbitrary length and I need to get rid of that garbage.

Every json entry starts with `{` and ends with `}` . I thought to iterate through string and count `{` and `}`, when numbers are the same to stop (it is going to work for now, I am gonna get time to find bug which generates trailing garbage).

How to implement this in python on efficient way, content can be over 32k ?

For example:

```
{'name':'Cverg', 'age':18, 'sex':'male'}iodsnd[erworkpweff,ccsd
```

valid part is

```
{'name':'Cverg', 'age':18, 'sex':'male'}
```

and garbage is

```
iodsnd[erworkpweff,ccsd
```

garbage is changeable and is random.

Comment: Can you give an example of the trailing garbage, and the beginning and end of your input?

Comment: @PhillipCloud I have added example with problem and valid part

Comment: That is *not* valid JSON; single quotes are not permitted.

Answer (score 6):

The [`json.JSONDecoder()` class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) can handle this without change:

```
import json

decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
result, index = decoder.raw_decode(string_with_trailing_garbage)
```

The `index` value points to where decoding ended.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note, the json module does not accept single quotes as valid json. Both string values and keys must be surrounded by double quotes. Otherwise you get:

```
ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

I thought maybe you could get away with values in single quotes, but it still complains. Martijn's answer is still best otherwise.